# Solutions to secure MQTT-SN over UDP with DTLS (or alternatives)

Tags: mqtt, security

We want to secure the transport of MQTT-SN messages send over UDP e.g. with DTLS.

Searching the internet showed that there are [considerations](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/mosquitto-dev/msg00926.html) and [activities](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt-sn.embedded-c/issues/90) on using DTLS to secure the transport of MQTT-SN messages over UDP but there doesn't seem to be much velocity behind them and I found no solution which seems to be ready for production.

**Question:**

1. Are you aware about any solutions for securing the transport of MQTT-SN messages over UDP which are ready right now?
2. Any ideas what else to investigate beside DTLS?

Comment: The discussions you linked to are the guys most likely to be working on this sort of thing, so if they've not got to it yet you might be out of luck. The only other option I can think of instead of DTLS is encrypted/signed payloads (which is likely to bulk up the payload a lot)

Answer (score 3):

Using DTLS in the internet is just not that easy :-).

Depending on your communication environment (e.g. NATs in between) it requires either frequently resumption handshakes, or [DTLS 1.2 Connection ID](https://github.com/tlswg/dtls-conn-id/blob/master/draft-ietf-tls-dtls-connection-id.md), or maybe DTLS 1.3 (if you find a implementation, which supports the CID there).

Your both links are Eclipse Open Source Projects. And Open Source lives from contributions of those, who are interested in a topic.
So don't hesitate to start with your own experiments. For java, you may consider to use DTLS from [CoAP/DTLS Californium/Scandium](https://github.com/eclipse/californium)